# Python rename ftp upload files delete

Tags: python, upload, ftp, rename

I have a script that renames files before uploading them to an FTP. First it searched for the pattern "_768x432_1700_m30_" and if it find it the pattern gets replaced by "*new*" - then it uploads all ".mp4" files in the directory to an FTP server. But for some reason I can't seem to delete the files after them have been uploaded? Also is there a better way of doing this script? (I am fairly new to python)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import glob
import fnmatch
import sys
import ftplib
import shutil
import re
from ftplib import FTP



Host='xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.com'
User='xxxxxxx'
Passwd='xxxxxxx'

ftp = ftplib.FTP(Host,User,Passwd) # Connect


dest_dir = '/8619/_!/xxxx/xx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx/'
Origin_dir = '/8619/_!/xxxx/xx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx/'
pattern = '*.mp4'
file_list = os.listdir(Origin_dir)


for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(Origin_dir, "*_768x432_1700_m30_*")):
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace('_768x432_1700_m30_','_new_' ))
    video_list = fnmatch.filter(filename, pattern)

print(video_list)

print "Checking %s for files" % Origin_dir
for files in file_list:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(files, pattern):
        print(files)
        print "logging into %s FTP" % Host
        ftp = FTP(Host)
        ftp.login(User, Passwd)
        ftp.cwd(dest_dir)
        print "uploading files to %s" % Host
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + dest_dir+files, open(Origin_dir+files, "rb"), 1024)
        ftp.close
        print 'FTP connection has been closed'
```

Comment: Should that be `ftp.close()` instead of `ftp.close`?

Comment: Hi - when I try and delete "files" the variable that collects all the *.mp4 files in the directory and uploads them - I can't seem to work out how to delete the files after upload. So if I try os.remove(files) the script just closes

Comment: So I would like the script to delete the files after they have been uploaded. Sorry I wasn't being more clear

Comment: To have the script delete the file, use the `os.unlink()` function.  I would caution regarding deleting content.  If an error occurs then you don't want to lose your only copy of the data.

Comment: Its ok to loose the files - they are transcodes from source so we can always re-generate them and they will appear in the Origin_dest again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following line
    `ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + dest_dir+files, open(Origin_dir+files, "rb"), 1024)`
you open a file, but you don't keep a reference to it and close it.  On Windows (I assume you are running this on Windows), a file can not be deleted while a process has it open.

Try the following instead:

```
print "uploading files to %s" % Host
with open(Origin_dir+files, "rb") as f:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + dest_dir+files, f, 1024)
ftp.close()
print 'FTP connection has been closed'
```

The differences are:

- use a with-statement to ensure the file is closed whether successful or an exception is raised
- assign the result of the `open()` call to a name (`f`)
- added missing parenthesis to `ftp.close()` so the function is called.

Comment: Thank you for this - I am running it on a Xserve or red hat linux. But let me try your recommendations out.